# Why I still can see my php code through 'view source' in my browser while using xampp

Tags: php, web-applications

I'm running XAMPP on my computer. I build an **index.php** and store it under `xampp/htdocs/domain` folder.

Everything works fine for me. But when I click **view source**, I still can see through all my PHP code and especially MySQL database password. Is that normal? what should I do?

```
<?php
include("header.php");
//phpinfo();
if (isset($_GET['aid']) && is_numeric($_GET['aid'])) {
    $aid = (int) $_GET['aid'];
} else { $aid = 1; }
// mysqli $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase); 
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT entries.*, categories.cat FROM entries, categories WHERE entries.cat_id = categories.id ORDER BY dateposted asc limit 0,5");
$row_12 = $result->num_r
```

My website is working at all. Only when I click 'view source' on the successful page, it show all my php code and MySQL statement.

To my point of view, it should show the html syntax instead. It's like the rendering is not working at all. I'm working with XAMPP v3.2.2  and I'm viewing my website using localhost/domain.

Comment: Surely not. Paste your code erasing secret credentials and let us see what you've done wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: the issue has been resolved @Mahfuzul Alam

Answer (score 0):

If the code is not in  tag it will be shown, make sure you have this on the start and end also make sure you don't have any comment indicators

Comment: my website is working well. no problem with the website. but when i click 'view source' on the page, it show my php and MySQL statement. it's like the rendering is not working at all.